# how to add custom views to alertdialog in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add custom views(chekbox and two radio buttons) as shown in image below in alertdialog but not succeded.

[image]

Please suggest me a way to get views as shown in the image.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead of AlertDialog.

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

        //do something with your view

        builder.setView(viewRoot);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

`R.layout.dialog_view`  - it's your view, which you want to display

Answer (score 0):

You can build dialog with custom layout. 
Here's some tutorial how to do that:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/